# mprotect syscall not working

Tags: linux, shellcode, syscall

I want to modify the protection of the .text segment to RWX using a shellcode. In the shellcode, I can issue the syscall for mprotect however it's not working.

Per the sys_mprotect definition, it takes the parameters as shown below:

```
rdi -> start_address
rsi -> length
rdx -> protection
```

**Note:** I have corrected the parameters above. The issue is not related to the parameter sequence.

so, I'm issuing the syscall as shown below:

```
push 0xA
pop rax
push 0x7
pop rdx
mov rdi, start_address
mov rsi, 0x1000
syscall
```

At the time of syscall, I verified that the registers are set properly.

start_address points to the main() subroutine inside the .text section which I want to modify.

However, the syscall does not modify the protection to RWX after execution. I verified the protection by viewing segments in IDA Pro.

Per the syscall_mprotect definition, the other registers don't have to be configured specifically for this syscall. So, I am not sure why this syscall is not working?

**Update:** I modified the start_address so that it's page aligned.

```
start_address = start_address - (start_address % 4096)
```

Now, syscall_mprotect does not return a negative value. It returns 0. However, the .text segment still doesn't show the writable flag.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameters for `mprotect` are not correct. Here's the correct order

```
start: rdi
len:   rsi
prot:  rdx
```

The shellcode that works is

```
push 0xA
pop rax
push 0x7
pop rdx
call x
x:pop rdi
and rdi, 0xfffffffffffff000
mov rsi, 0x1000
syscall
```

The `call x x: pop rdi` is used to get the current `rip`. Assuming the code is in `.text` this should work.
Link for reference on syscalls [x86](https://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/) [x64](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/)

Comment: I made an error while writing the post. So, that's not the issue here. I was using the correct parameters while executing the code. And in my case, the shellcode is not executing in the .text section. It is executing in another mapped region of the process. I'll check again. As I mentioned in the update of my post, if I align start address to page boundary, then mprotect returns 0x0 (success) instead of an error. However, the "W" flag for the .text segment is still not shown enabled in the program segments section of IDA Pro.

Comment: can you check /proc/pid/maps ?

Comment: Yes, I'll check that. The syscall does work properly, it seems that IDA Pro does not update the protection flags for program segments in real time.

Answer (score 1):

IDA does not update memory map after each step since it can potentially take a long time. You can try to either use “run to”(F4) instead of stepping or force refresh by calling `refresh_debugger_memory()` IDC function.